# What does an uninitialized but typed class variable do?

Tags: python, class

What is `a` in

```
class Foo:
   a: int
```

I can create a `Foo` no problem, but if I try to access `a`, either on the class or instance, I get an `AttributeError`. If I drop the `int`, I get

> NameError: name 'a' is not defined

before I even refer to `Foo`. I'm not surprised by that, but the fact that I can instantiate `Foo` with the type hint suggests `a` exists in some form, else I would expect the latter `NameError`.

Comment: Type hints don't actually do anything by default. A type hint for something doesn't mean the thing exists.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I understand that the type hint doesn't mean it exists. What I think means it exists is that I'm no longer seeing a `NameError`, as though the type hint has magically made the name valid, but at the same time not an attribute - some kind of variable limbo

Comment: You've misunderstood what's going on. `a` on its own fails because it's trying to look up a variable that doesn't exist. `a: int` doesn't involve a variable lookup; it just doesn't care whether `a` exists at all.

Comment: You must be actually confused with Python dataclasses behaviour

Comment: @AnthonyPerot not really. I'm aware this is standard syntax for dataclasses. I just wondered why it's also valid for normal classes, and what it means in that case